# How to draw an CGImage with some alpha transparency?

Tags: iphone

Want to draw an UIImageView which has an CGImage, and the UIImageView has alpha 0.5f. But this CGContextDrawImage function doesnt take an transparency value. So how could I draw an image slightly transparent?

To be clear: The image itself is not transparent, but I want it to be "dimmed" a little bit. Just like you would do with an UIImageView and some alpha like 0.5f :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I haven't tried this but try calling `CGContextSetAlpha()` before `CGContextDrawImage()`.